How to create editable powerpoint from markdown, preferably using pandoc?
I am converting markdown to powerpoint using pandoc.
The resulting file is editable, but the pandoc rendered text and images are not editable.
I am using pandoc 3.4 on windows from gitbash
pandoc my.md -o my.pptx

output is fast, looks great, but I need to share it with others who want to edit the pptx directly.
Is there a way to export editable content?

although I don't entirely understand why yet, when I added the standalone parameter -s, I got a document that is less beautifully rendered but editable.
I'll experiment with templates and see how I go.
pandoc my.md -o my.pptx -s


With pandoc 3.3 and PowerPoint 2021, I get editable PowerPoint slides without using -s. I am starting the pandoc command out of a cmd.exe box.

thanks Axel, what command parameters do you use to produce powerpoint?

pandoc my.md -o my.pptx as in your original question.
